# Program Hangs During IF/Else SQL Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am creating a registration application which works two ways: Online and Offline. We use barcodes to scan ourselves into the application. When you scan the online barcode it will give you 6 numbers and an "L" e.g. 242565L , and the program will pick this up and search the SQL database for the corresponding ID number. And the offline barcode holds a name text value with a "*" e.g. Smith, John*.

When i run it and scan the online barcode it works fine.
But when i disconnect from the internet so it doesnt find a database, and scan my code , it picks up 1 letter and freezes and just hangs until i stop the process.

Any Ideas please ? New to C#

Here is the main code:

```
            {
            SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection("DataSource=DATABASE;Initial Catalog=imis;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            Object returnValue;

            string txtend = textBox1.Text;
            try
            {
                DBConnection.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                DBConnection.Close();
            }
            if (DBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.Length != 7) return;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT last_name +', '+ first_name +'\t ('+major_key+')\t' from name where id ='" + textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "") + "'";
                // MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", ""));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = DBConnection;
                // sqlConnection1.Open();
                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "\t (" + textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "") + ")";
                DBConnection.Close();


                if (listBox1.Items.Contains(returnValue))
                {

                    for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
                    {
                        string removelistitem = returnValue.ToString();
                        if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
                        {
                            // listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
                        }

                    }
                }
                else

                    listBox1.Items.Add(returnValue);

                textBox1.Text = null;

                if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0) { DisableCloseButton(); }
                else
                {

                    EnableCloseButton();
                }
                label6.Text = "Currently " + listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " in attendance.";
            }

            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string lastTwoChars = txtend.Substring(txtend.Length - 1);

                    returnValue = textBox1.Text.Replace(@"*", "");

                    if (lastTwoChars != "*") return;
                    {
                        if (listBox1.Items.Contains(returnValue))
                        {
                            for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
                            {
                                string removelistitem = returnValue.ToString();
                                if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
                                {
                                    //listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            listBox1.Items.Add(returnValue);
                        textBox1.Text = null;
                        if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0) { DisableCloseButton(); }
                        else
                        {
                            EnableCloseButton();
                        }
                        label6.Text = "Currently " + listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " in attendance.";
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: what's your SQL timeout? It's probably waiting (*literally*)forever to connect to SQL.

Comment: Sepecify a [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.asp) in your SqlCommand

Comment: oh god, please use EntityFramework to do your database queries.

Comment: @Aviatrix, OEMs such as EF are not for everyone. We don't use them commercially because they add too great a performance overhead. We do all our SQL using flat simple ADO.Net, Ryan is obviously just a beginner too so it's much better to learn what EF is actually doing under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to debug it. pause the program when it hangs and see where it hangs. if it hangs on the SQL query you might want to put a timeout on it.

also you shouldn't create the query like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT last_name +', '+ first_name +'\t ('+major_key+')\t' from name where id ='" + textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "") + "'";
```

it's open to sql injections.

use [parameterized sql](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) or other form of protection:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT last_name +', '+ first_name +'\t ('+major_key+')\t' from name where id =@Name"

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "")));
```

**EDIT**

if you want to put a timeout on the connection you can look here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx):
you can set the timeout parameter in the connection string or simply

```
DBConnection.ConnectionTimeout = yourTime;
```

that will make the connection fail after it waited for the timeout parameter.

Comment: What [SQL injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx) is for reference

Comment: Thanks NoIdeaForName, will try just now. And thanks Liam will also add that in. Yes I am a beginner haha

Comment: It's Hanging at DBConnection.Open();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a try..catch to establish if you have an active db connection, use a 'using' block instead.

Its more efficient and will automatically close/destroy the db connection when its no longer needed.

This way you can move your try catch block inside the using statement and catch errors related to your code without worrying if you have an open db connection, or the state of the internet connection.

In this example ive taken the code from my own code base, and i'm using an oracle db connection.  you need to substitute the word 'Oracle' for 'SQL' 
Note param declaration is slightly different between db's. Oracle uses ":" and MsSql uses '@' to specify parameters.

eg.

```
  DataSet myDataSet= new DataSet();

  using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
   {
     using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
       {
        cmd.BindByName = true;

        #region SQL Core
           StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
           sql.Append(" <Your SQL Here> ");
        #endregion

        #region - ADD SQLParameter
          // use Parameters to avoid SQL Injection like @param1
          sql.Append(" AND (columnname = @param1 ");
          OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("@param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2); 
          param1.Value = yourValue;

          cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        #endregion

        cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        try
          {
             conn.Open();
             try
             {
               OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
               adapter.Fill(myDataSet, "myDataSetName");
             }
             catch (Exception myex)
             {
               //Handle General Exception
                Console.Write(myex);
             }
          }
          Catch (OracleException myex)
          {
            //Handle Oracle Exception
              Console.Write(myex);
          }
       }//end of inner 'using'
    }//end of outer 'using'

//Now you have a populated Data Set, you can loop over it extracting values.
//This acts like an offline record set
//Or you can Bind MyDataSet to a GridView to see the data in your offline table.

   //Output Result set in expected XML format and return
   DataTable dataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];

   if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
     for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
       DataRow dataRow = dataTable.Rows[i];
       for (int x = 0; x < dataTable.Columns.Count; x++)
       {
       //dataTable.Rows[i].Table.Columns[x].ColumnName.ToString()
       if (dataTable.Rows[i].Table.Columns[x].ColumnName == "YourColumnName") 
       { 
         //Get value with dataRow[x]
       }
      }//end 2nd for
     }//end 1st for
    }//end outer if.
```

Apologies if there are any syntax errors, this is all edited without intellisense.
Its just to give you the gist. that's all.

By using an offline dataset, you will get less application hangs.